# Is it possible to upload a web referral app to the apple store?

Tags: ios, app-store

I want to create a very simple app and upload it to the apple store.
The app works as follow : when you click on the app it will open safari browser with a website URL, after that the app closes.
I heard from some developers that this app won't be approved to the apple store.
Is this true? I don't have a developer account at Apple so I can't check their official guidelines.

Comment: Developer accounts with Apple are free.  You only have to pay for distributing applications.  You should register for free instead of asking Stack Overflow to read the page for you.

Comment: didn't know it was free, if i'd known that i would look that myself .

Answer (score 3):

This will definitely be rejected:

> **2.12.** Apps that are not very useful, unique, *are simply web sites bundled as Apps*, or do not provide any lasting entertainment value may be rejected.
>
> **12.3.** Apps that are simply web clippings, content aggregators, or a collection of links, may be rejected.

If you want a link to your web site as an application, you don't need to create an app for that. A user can add a link to your web site to their home screen from Safari: http://support.apple.com/kb/TI42